# AVAssetWriter: how to write to a single file multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am able to record video and save it in documents directory using AVFondation, now i want to re-open that saved video file and start recording again from the end of that file, is that possible or do i have to create multiple video files and merge them, please advise!

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to get the AVAssetWriter mux to append to an existing file. And of course if you need to prepend all the existing data when starting a new file, you will be slow to start.

An alternative is to start a new temporary file, and copy the data in the background into a third file, using something similar to http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html. That is, you have file 1, which was closed when you suspended. You start writing to file 2 when you resume, and simultaneously read from 1 and write to a new file 3. when you've exhausted 1, you can read from file 2 (using the example code linked to above) and append that to file 3.

G

Comment: Hi, could you provide some sample code that illustrates this solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the saved video, and then append the recorded video in NSData format, and rewrite the whole data again.. You can use NSMutableData to appendData..

Comment: thanks but I think, that would take same time as merging both videos, i want to use the existing file, so that recording can be started at minimum time.

Comment: Yes you will have to get the previous data saved in the file, you can get that by reading the video file, and just append with the latest data you have and then write back the whole data..